# R Shiny: Analysing user data in deployed app

Tags: r, shiny

I am finally trying to make a Shiny app. I am trying to upload a .xlsx file to the app, and then apply some analysis and download the output as a separate .xlsx file. The code for analysis and taking output works when run directly outside Shiny and I use it on daily, so I am simply trying to call it via `source` and save the duplicated work. Here is what I am trying with Shiny.

I was having problems in calling the file from the W2S.R script, while avoiding errors. I found a way to avoid the errors. The below code is a barebones model of that. However, now I cannot get the actual input to work (Output works fine, one table output on-screen and one XLSX output off-screen).

I am using `W2S <- input$W2S1` inside W2S.R script, but it is not recognising the variable `input`, which it does if used in the server function directly. How do I get it to work inside the script? Or is there any other workaround?

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
   titlePanel(h1("Goods In Transit Analysis", align="center")),
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         fileInput("W2S1", label="Select GIT W2S file")
      ),
      mainPanel(
        tableOutput("contents")
      )
   )
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$contents <- renderTable(if(is.null(input$W2S1)){return(NULL)}
                                 else{source("./W2S.R")})
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I will update once I get the input to work. Please help.

EDIT: Made some progress, as noted above. So updated the new code.

Answer (score 0):

Finally nailed it. I  needed an `observe` function and use the `$datapath` argument.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
   # Application title
   titlePanel(h1("Goods In Transit Analysis", align="center")),
   # Sidebar iputs
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         fileInput(inputId="W2S", label="Select GIT W2S file")
      ),
      # On Screen output
      mainPanel(
        h3(textOutput("filePath")),
        tableOutput("contents")
      )
   )
)
# Underlining code for output
server <- function(input, output) {
  observe({
    source("./Code/W2S.R")
    W2S <- input$W2S
    output$contents <- renderTable(if(is.null(W2S)){return(NULL)}
                                   else{W2S_F(W2S$datapath)})
  })
}
# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Please edit any relevant information into your original post. The space here is for answers only.

Comment: @BenBarnes updated the question and deleted the answer. Thank you.

Comment: nailed it, finally.